# Does ng-packagr generate script who can run in the browser like normal js?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng-packagr

Can I use [ng-packagr](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues) to build library with one script file that can run on the browser in the html by import as `<script src="bundle.js"></script>`?

For example I have `main.ts` that do `console.log('hello');` and I want to create `index.html` and import this code: `<script src="main.js"></script>`.

Is it possible to do that with `ng-packagr`? because I can see that I generate files: `esm2020`,`fesm2015`, `fesm2020` and those types are not compatibility with all browsers

And I don't care if the script is wrapped by webpack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ng-packagr is meant to be used to build angular libraries, not standalone libraries.